# Java (JUnit 4.xx) How to force call an exception in the try block with a void method using mocking tools?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

Here is a snippet of my code. I want to force call the catch block with WakeupException.

```
public void run() {

try {
         try {
        while (true) {
            LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, "run()", "Attempting to Poll");
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(10000);
            if (records.count() == 0) {
                LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, "run()", "No Response. Invalid Topic");
                break;
            }
            else if(records.count()>0) {
                LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, "run()", "Response Received");
            }
        }

    }

    } catch (WakeupException e) {
        consumer.close();
    }

}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
@Test(expected = WakeupException.class)
public void failRun() throws WakeupException, IOException {

    KafkaConsumerForTests consumerThread3;
    consumerThread3 = Mockito.mock(KafkaConsumerForTests.class);

    doThrow(new WakeupException()).when(consumerThread3).run();
    //Mockito.when(consumerThread2.run()).thenThrow(new WakeupException());

    consumerThread3.run();

}
```

I just want to call the WakeupException so that I get line coverage for that block of code. What would I do. This is a void method by the way. I'm open to suggestions involving PowerMock as well.

Comment: "*I just want to call the WakeupException so that I get line coverage for that block of code.*" - Wrong approach. Don't test for the sake of the test or coverage. Test to verify behaviour. --- You mock the wrong thing. Mock a call within the `try`-block that could actually throw a `WakeupException`.

Comment: Are you trying to test your mock? You should not mock the method you're trying to test.

Comment: Could you perhaps add what is inside code which actually require you to add the try catch? that is also the thing you have to mock in order to test it correctly. You should perhaps look into Dependency Injection for this case.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to test for behavior. I understand. I updated my question with code from my try block. @Wisienkas I don't know what to mock out and how to.

Comment: @SandeepNamburi it is probably the consumer which requires the try-catch. If you are setting it somewhere you could try to inject it into the class from your unit test. Usual a code smell would be if your design is not testable, you could consider a TDD approach to avoid that in the future :)

Comment: How does `consumer` get set in your `KafkaConsumerForTests` object?  That's the object you want to have a mock for, and you'll need some way of injecting it.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing the code, I am quite sure that the call we want to mock is `consumer.poll(...)`. I am not an expert in using Kafka so take everything from here with a grain of salt. Seeing that `consumer` is an attribute of the class under test, it should be possible to inject a mocked instance into the class under test and throw the `WakeupException` we need. Instead of (or additional to - your decision) the class under test, we create a(n additional) mock of the `consumer` and mock its `poll(...)`-method to throw the desired `WakeupException` when called. Instead of mocking the call to `consumerThread3.run()`, we mock the call to `consumer.poll(...)`.

---

A remark on your question: "*I just want to call the `WakeupException` so that I get line coverage*" - This should never be the reason to write a test. A test should test behaviour. If there is no behaviour to test (which is rarely the case), do not write a test.

---

OP edited the question and added some additional information. I am quite confident that the first paragraph of this post should answer the question. The other paragraphs were written before OP added the relevant code in the `try`-block. They are written on a more abstract level. The interested reader may read them, but this is not necessary to understand the answer.

お楽しみください! - Please enjoy!

---

We want to verify the behaviour of the `catch`-block. In productive code, something in the `try`-block would throw the corresponding `Exception` triggering the `catch`-block. Thus, in order to test the `catch`-block, we should mock something in the `try`-block to throw said `Exception`.

If mocking a call within the block seems impossible, that may be due to the fact that the code was not developed test-driven. You see, an upside of [Test-Driven Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) is that you intrinsically generate testable code. If we are stuck with untestable/hard to test code, w ehave two (or maybe three) options:

- Leave it as is, do not test it. This can be a valid answer if there is no behaviour to test.
- Rewrite the code, make it testable. Depending on the structure of your project this could take from five minutes up to 2 weeks or more. Hard to say without knowing the codebase
- Use unconventional tools. Normal mocking frameworks like [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) have certain limittations, e.g. [for Mockito mocking of `static` or `final` methods is not supported](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ). Other tools, like [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock), aim to eliminate those limitations. But be warned: PowerMock operates on bytecode level. This means that

  - we are not necessarily testing the bytecode we use in production
  - this can screw with other tools, e.g. [JaCoCo](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/).

  Those tools should be your last resort only and used sparsely.

Comment: @Turing85 Thank you so much I figured it out. I mocked out the consumer.poll and it worked. Thanks everyone for all the help!